# Unknown Publisher Using SHA256RSA for Signing ClickOnce Manifests

Tags: visual-studio, clickonce, code-signing, signtool

I created a self-signed CA certificate and placed it in the Current User Trusted Root Certification Authorities Certificate Store. I then created a Software Publisher Certificate using:

```
makecert -n "CN=Temp Name, O=Temp Corporation, C=US" -h 0 ^
         -eku "1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.3,1.3.6.1.4.1.311.10.3.13" ^
         -e 01/01/2015 -ic "Temp CA.cer" -iv "Temp.pvk" ^
         -sv "Temp SPC.pvk" -a sha256 "Temp SPC.cer"
```

... And merged the resulting files into a pfx file like so:

```
Pvk2Pfx /pvk "Temp SPC.pvk" /spc "Temp SPC.cer" /pfx "Temp SPC.pfx"
```

I went on to use this pfx file for signing the ClickOnce Manifests of a simple console application with Visual Studio (2013), and all was well. However, when testing the resulting Setup.exe, I noticed that Application Install - Security Warning dialog reported the publisher to be unknown.

Following [this MSDN guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/jj835832%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), I managed to get things working as expected by excluding the `-a sha256` flag, resulting in:

```
makecert -n "CN=Temp Name, O=Temp Corporation, C=US" -h 0 ^
         -eku "1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.3,1.3.6.1.4.1.311.10.3.13" ^
         -e 01/01/2015 -ic "Temp CA.cer" -iv "Temp.pvk" ^
         -sv "Temp SPC.pvk" "Temp SPC.cer"
```

I don't get this. Why does specifying `-a sha256` for the SPC result in the publisher being "unknown" (and a much angrier looking dialog, yellow shield and all)?

---

**Edit:** Actually, it gets a bit weirder still; I just tried changing to `-a sha512`, and *that works too*:

```
makecert /n "CN=Temp Name, O=Temp Corporation, C=US" /h 0 ^
         /eku "1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.3,1.3.6.1.4.1.311.10.3.13" ^
         /e 01/01/2015 -ic "Temp CA.cer" -iv "Temp.pvk" ^
         /sv "Temp SPC.pvk" -a sha512 "Temp SPC.cer"
```